# Use ndk toolchain for non-android projects

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, c++builder

I was wondering if someone has experimented with using Google's NDK build to compile code for standard linux x86/arm that is not targeted for android. I think it should be straight forward by swapping out some paths, but am feeling lazy.

The reason I need this is that I have android app which has a jni component, which i would like to compile for linux as well.

Comment: The ndk builds against bionic libc and android's kernel abi.  It would be easier to use a normal toolchain - if you build against bionic you will at minimum need to install those system libraries.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you'd be linking against a different libc, the android ABI isn't strictly equivalent to even x86 Linux. I don't remember what differences there are, but they aren't guaranteed to be compatible.